# Response for preflight does not have HTTP ok status. API REST angular 5

Tags: angular, api, asp.net-web-api

Tengo una aplicación en Angular 4 que consume un servicio en ASP .Net Core y no hay ningún problema. Esta misma aplicación también consume datos de otro servicio pero este es en ASP .Net es un API REST,

Este es el codigo de mi Servicio

```
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("api/Documentos/getString")]
    public string getString()
    {
        return "ok";
    }
```

y asi es como lo estoy consumiendo desde Angular

```
  constructor(private httpClient: HttpClient) {
      this.header = { headers: new HttpHeaders({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' })};
  }

  getString(): Observable<any> {
       return this.httpClient.get("http://localhost:60402/api/Documentos/getString", this.header);
  }
```

El error que me da es el siguiente.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Quizá me falta agregar algo en el webConfig pero la verdad no lo se, ¿alguna solución?

Comment: Tu aplicación servidora está retornando un 405 (Method not allowed). Esto es porque el navegador, antes de hacerle la petición `GET` desde javascript, hace una petición previa `OPTIONS` y analiza la respuesta del servidor buscando ciertas cabeceras. Si el servidor responde como un error (como es tu caso), o si las cabeceras que busca no están presentes, el navegador aborta la petición. Debes asegurarte de que el servidor admite el verbo OPTIONS sobre esa ruta y que retorna las cabeceras CORS apropiadas. No sé cómo se hace eso en ASP .NET :-(

Comment: Mira a ver si [esta información de Microsoft sobre CORS en ASP.NET](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/aspnet/web-api/overview/security/enabling-cross-origin-requests-in-web-api)  te ayuda

Comment: he seguido lo que dice el link, agregue config.EnableCors(); en WebApiConfig.Register y agregue [EnableCors(origins: "*", headers: "*", methods: "*")] en mi controlador pero sigue  sucediendo lo mismo

Comment: ahora me aparece "Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: The 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header contains multiple values '*, *', but only one is allowed. Origin 'http://localhost:4200' is therefore not allowed access."

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

Web.config

httpProtocol

customHeaders

```
<add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />

<add name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" value="*" />

<add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="x-requested-with, Content-Type, origin, authorization, accept, client-security-token" />
```

Global.asax

protected void Application_BeginRequest()
{
if (Request.Headers.AllKeys.Contains("Origin") && Request.HttpMethod == "OPTIONS")
{
// These headers are handling the "pre-flight" OPTIONS call sent by the browser
HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, POST, PUT, DELETE");
HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type, Accept");
HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true");
HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Max-Age", "1728000");
HttpContext.Current.Response.End();
}
}